# Orthogonal Complement

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal, orthogonality

"Let $\Bbb{V}$ be a vector space with an inner product $<\cdot,\cdot>$, and $S\subset\Bbb{V}$. We define the orthogonal complement of $S$, denoted by $S^{\perp}$, as follows:
$$S^{\perp}=\left\{v\in\Bbb{V}|<v,u>=0,\forall u\in S\right\}.$$
Let $\Bbb{V}=\Bbb{R}^2$ with the usual sum and product by scalar, and $S=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2|x+y=1\}.$ Find $S^{\perp}$."
I have done this exercise but I don't know if it is correct. I found $S^{\perp}=\{(0,0)\}$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is the answer I got. But the important thing is if you did it correctly.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The point is that $S$, although it's geometrically a line, does not pass through the origin and is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In fact the span of $S$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it makes sense that there is no non-zero vector orthogonal to all of $S$.

Comment: Thank you guys! I have done this way:  if $<(a,b),(x,1-x)>=0,\forall x\in \Bbb{R}$ then $(a,b)\in S^{\perp}$. We yield $<(a,b),(x,1-x)>=0, \forall x\in \Bbb{R} \implies (a-b)x+b=0, \forall x\in \Bbb{R}$. Then $a=b=0$. @EWHLee

Comment: @Anderson: Yes, that's right. In fact, it is simpler to note that $(1,0),(0,1) \in S$, so $\langle(1,0),(x,y)\rangle = 0$ implies that $x=0$, and $\langle(0,1),(x,y)\rangle = 0$ implies that $y=0$ :)